# Prevent ListView Scroll to top on notifyDAtaSetChanged

Tags: android

I'm using a listView that gets notifyDataSetChanged() called every few seconds and if user is scrolling down, he's automatically scrolled to top.

What could be the reason?
I've not used any .setSelection(0), or other methods that force scrolling. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: nope! I thought there must be some notifyDataSetChanged, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: The answer is here: just try it out
http://vikinghammer.com/2011/06/17/android-listview-maintain-your-scroll-position-when-you-refresh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used CursorAdapter to populate listview, problem went away.